Can you create a type to represent a typeguard
Is it possible to create a type that represents a typeguard, for example if you wanted to have a type to enforce creation of an object of where the keys represent the typeof return value of expected true type guard predicate resolution, as shown below:
type ValueMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};

type Value = ValueMap[keyof ValueMap];

You have a value that can be string or number.
It's possible to create a type like this that checks the value:
type Guards = { [K in keyof ValueMap]: (value: Value) => boolean };

but the functions are not typed as type guards, I would like something like:
type TypedGuards = { [K in keyof ValueMap]: (value: Value):value is K => boolean };

But this is invalid syntax.
I would like for the type to be usable so that
const guards: Guards = {
  number: (value) => true,
  string: (value) => true,
};

infers the correct type in some conditional statement like if(guard(value)){...}
So basically would like same outcome as
const typeGuards = {
  number: (value: Value): value is number => true,
  string: (value: Value): value is string => true,
};

but I would like to create a type to represent this.
If I do
const typeGuards = {
  number: (value: Value): value is number => true,
  string: (value: Value): value is string => true,
};

type TypeGuards = typeof typeGuards

I do get
type TypeGuards = {
    number: (value: Value) => value is number;
    string: (value: Value) => value is string;
}

but I would like to express this explicitly as a type.
Thanks

Like this? I could write up an answer if that meets your needs. I'm confused about why you missed this, though. (value: Value):value is K => boolean is clearly invalid syntax; presumably you meant to replace boolean with value is K instead of appending it. Once you fix that, then you must be aware that K is just the key, not the type, and you need to look things up in ValueMap.  But once you fix that the problem goes away completely. I feel like I just fixed a few typos to start looking at the question and then it's over. What am I missing?

Hi, yeah that's great thank. Yea I'm not sure, now that I see it, it seems very clear. I think I just got a bit muddled up with the usual inline syntax for typeguard's where the return value should be a boolean but the function specifies it's a typeguard with the (value: Value):value is K => boolean syntax. Thanks

as in somewhere I thought that I had to also specify that the function should return a boolean, but I guess that's taken care of implicitly by the return type being <arg> is <type>

That's just an inline return type annotation for an arrow function value, like (arg: A): R => r, but the type of that function is (arg: A) => R. Just like a regular function looks like function f(arg: A): R {} but the type is (arg: A) => R or possibly {(arg:A): R}. So it's essentially just typo or syntax issues.  There's nothing specific to type guards going on here except that the return type is a type predicate

You can write
type Guards = { [K in keyof ValueMap]:
    (value: Value) => value is ValueMap[K]
};
/* type Guards = {
    string: (value: Value) => value is string;
    number: (value: Value) => value is number;
} */

You need to index into ValueMap with K to get the right type (K is just "string", not string).
And the type of a type guard function is (value: Value) => value is string, not (value: Value): value is string => boolean. The latter is just syntactically invalid.  Indeed when you wrote your function manually and looked at the type, it was of the form (value: Value) => value is string.
If you fix the indexed access and the syntactic typo stuff, it works as expected.
Playground link to code
